# How to Implement RxJava TextChange in RxSwift

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextfield, rx-swift

I want to implement AutoComplete Text field with RxSwift in swift 3.

I have this code in java and it works well, but I don't know to implement it swift 3 with RxSwift.
I have searched for TextChange in rxSwift but I couldn't find anything!

here is my code.

```
RxTextView.textChanges(mEtAddress)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter(s -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
                .compose(bindUntilEvent(FragmentEvent.STOP))
                .flatMap(q -> mReactiveLocationProvider.getPlaceAutocompletePredictions(
                        q, new LatLngBounds(
                                new LatLng(SOUTHWEST_LATITUDE, SOUTHWEST_LONGITUDE),
                                new LatLng(NORTHEAST_LATITUDE, NORTHEAST_LONGITUDE)), null))
                .subscribe(buffer -> {
                    List<AutocompleteInfo> infos = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : buffer) {
                        infos.add(new AutocompleteInfo(prediction.getFullText(null).toString(), prediction.getPlaceId()));
                    }
                    buffer.release();
                    mPlaceSuggestionsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, infos));
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `RxCocoa` for reactive extensions to `UIKit`. 
UITextFied is extended and has property `rx`.
You can use reactive text property:

```
textField.rx.text...
```